# Convergence of the sum of squares of averages of a sequence whose sum of squares is convergent

Tags: sequences-and-series, sums-of-squares

Can we find a sequence $u_n$ of positive real numbers such that 
$\sum_{n=1}^\infty u_n^2$ is finite,  yet $\sum_{n=1}^\infty ({u_1+u_2+...+u_n\over n})^2$ is infinite ?

After several attempts, I think this is not possible, but I can't prove that the finiteness of the first sum implies the finiteness of the second sum.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Hardy's inequality says
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{a_1+\cdots+a_n}{n}\right)^p\le \left(\frac{p}{p-1}\right)^{p}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n^p$$
for any $p>1$.

Comment: You're welcome! A reference is, of course, Hardy-Littlewood-Polya's "Inequalities".